# Vaadin 14.6.1 - Error: Can't resolve 'lumo-css-framework/all-classes.css'

Tags: css, spring, gradle, migration, vaadin-flow

I am migrating a Vaadin Springboot/Gradle application from Vaadin 14.5.1 to  14.6.1. I copied the new file(s) from the themes folder from a freshly generated app from [start.vaadin.com](https://start.vaadin.com/), in particular frontend/themes/my-app/styles.css

```
@import url('lumo-css-framework/all-classes.css');
```

When running the `vaadinBuildFrontend` task, I receive the following error (deep in other messages):

```
ERROR in ./themes/my-app/styles.css
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve 'lumo-css-framework/all-classes.css' in '/Users/<..>/my-app/frontend/themes/my-app
```

All build dependencies are seemingly the same as in the sample maven project. All generated files had been deleted prior to building the frontend.

After comparing the generated files, I found that the sample maven project contains `"lumo-css-framework": "^3.0.11"` in the generated `package.json`, while the gradle project does not contain this.

The environment:

- Spring 2.5.0
- Gradle 7.0.1
- Vaadin Gradle plugin 0.14.6.0
- macOS 11.2.3 and Centos 7

What am I missing in the setup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your project is missing the `lumo-css-framework` npm dependency. There are two ways you can add it:

1. `npm install --save lumo-css-framework`. This will store the dependency in `package.json` which contains a list of all npm dependencies needed in the project. It is academically wrong to say that `package.json` is auto generated as what Vaadin really does it populates `package.json` with whatever the Java side (mainly components) define as their npm dependencies. Any other dependency defined in `package.json` is left alone.
2. Annotate any Java class in the project with `@NpmDependency(value="lumo-css-framework", version="^3.0.11")`. This annotation will be used by Vaadin when figuring out what npm dependencies are needed for the project and then `package.json` will be updated based on the annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and advice. Running `npm install --save lumo-css-framework`works, until `gradle vaadinClean` is executed. The next build then creates a new `package.json`. So this is not a sustainable approach. Adding `@NpmPackage(value="lumo-css-framework", version="^3.0.11")`works as you suggested and fixes the problem. I still think, though, that Vaadin should figure this out automatically, as the documentation explicitly states that all themes are based on Lumo. Thumbs up for your suggestion anyways!. Thanks.

Comment: @macnixde - `lumo-css-framework` is not a requirement for using Vaadin. They are a set of utility CSS classes primarily for Fusion users. Projects generated with start.vaadin.com include some additional helpers and customization that aren't part of the framework which leads to some extra migration steps like this.